# problem trying to copy options from a select/option element to another void select in a DOMContentLoaded function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

im trying to copy the existing options from a select to another one after a DOMContentLoaded event and im having some strange behavior as a result:

```
<select id='select'>
    <option id='1'>option 1</option>
    <option id='2'>option 2</option>
    <option id='3'>option 3</option>
    <option id='4'>option 4</option>
</select>
<P>New option:</P>
<input type="text" name='new'>
<input type="button" value="crear" onclick='create()'></button>
<p>Edit</p>
<div id='editElement'>
<select name="selectEdit" id="selectEdit"></select>
<input type="text" id='edit'>
<input type="button" value="edit" >
<input type="button" value="remove" >
</div>
    <script>
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    select =  document.getElementById('select');
    selectEdit =  document.getElementById('selectEdit');
    for (let index = 0; index < select.length; index++) {
        selectEdit[index] = select[index];
        
    }   
    } );    
    </script>
```

some of the existing options from the 1st select are missing and in the second that im filling is incomplete too...i broke js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are not copying them, you are moving them.
To copy an element, you need use [`element.cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

```
selectEdit[index] = select[index].cloneNode(true);
```

And the reason why only some of them being moved is because when you move one element the `select` node list reduces by one, so in the next loop it skips one element.